# Реализация COM интерфейсов

Tags: c#, .net, com, dxgi

Хотелось бы узнать как правильно реализовывать работу с `COM` объектами, реализацией интерфейсов `IUnknown` а так же правильно маршаллировать передаваемые аргументы в функции импорта из `COM` библиотек.

В данный момент меня интересует как правильно реализовать работу с библиотекой `dxgi`.

Я посмотрел наследования объектов, и все сходится к одному, все интерфейсы `DXGI` наследуются от `IDXGIObject`, при этом данный интерфейс наследуется от `IUnknown`. Казалось бы все просто, организовать интерфейс `IDXGIObject` от него наследовать дополнительные интерфейсы, и работать с ними. Но, в моем случае я просто не понимаю как правильно это делается, и каким образом работать с методом который принимает 2 параметра к примеру вот этот:

```
HRESULT CreateDXGIFactory(
  REFIID riid,
  void   **ppFactory
);
```

Да, `REFIID` это всего лишь `typedef IID* REFIID`, но тут снова вопрос, что такое `IID` и как его маршаллировать из [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) в данный метод, содержащийся в библиотеке `dxgi`.

Все что пришло мне в голову, это примерно такая реализация, которую не проверял:

```
[Guid("aec22fb8-76f3-4639-9be0-28eb43a67a2e")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDXGIObject
{
    long SetPrivateData(
        [In] Guid refGuid,
        [In] uint dataSize,
        [In] IntPtr data);

    long SetPrivateDataInterface(
        [In] ref Guid name,
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object data);

    long GetPrivateData(
        [In] Guid name, 
        [In][Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] ref uint outDataSize,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] IntPtr data);
    ...
}
```

В работе такой реализации я очень сомневаюсь, ведь выглядит все это дело подозрительно просто. И не уверен в правильности переноса интерфейса из `dxgi.h`

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("aec22fb8-76f3-4639-9be0-28eb43a67a2e")
IDXGIObject : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetPrivateData( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        __in  REFGUID Name,
        /* [in] */ UINT DataSize,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        __in_bcount(DataSize)  const void *pData) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetPrivateDataInterface( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        __in  REFGUID Name,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        __in  const IUnknown *pUnknown) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPrivateData( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        __in  REFGUID Name,
        /* [annotation][out][in] */ 
        __inout  UINT *pDataSize,
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        __out_bcount(*pDataSize)  void *pData) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetParent( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        __in  REFIID riid,
        /* [annotation][retval][out] */ 
        __out  void **ppParent) = 0;

};
```

Правильно ли удалось мне перенести интерфейс? И как лучше это делать?

Comment: Атрибуты `[In]` и `[Out]` писать не нужно - они не для вас, а для компилятора. А `IntPtr data` лучше заменить на `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=1)] byte[] data`